# Snort Errors: ERROR: /etc/snort/snort.conf(0) Unable to open rules file "/etc/snort/snort.conf": No such file or directory

Tags: snort

First time Snort user and running into two issues. After installation on a Windows 10 machine, I am able to initialize snort via an elevated command prompt: **snort -A console**. While snort it running however I noticed "**Warning: No Preprocessors configured for policy 0.**" mixed into the console output.

A quick Stackoverflow search pointed me to run the following command to solve this, they said: This message indicates that no snort preprocessor is loaded. In order to get rid of this warning, please use the command: **snort -v -c /etc/snort/snort.conf**

But when I run this command I am greeted with another error:

**Running in IDS mode
        --== Initializing Snort ==--
Initializing Output Plugins!
Initializing Preprocessors!
Initializing Plug-ins!
Parsing Rules file "/etc/snort/snort.conf"
ERROR: /etc/snort/snort.conf(0) Unable to open rules file "/etc/snort/snort.conf": No such file or directory.
Fatal Error, Quitting..**

This is where I get lost since that's where I have the config file (initally it was just /etc/snort.conf, but created a snort folder so the directory / file exists).

If anyone has any insight into this I would be more than grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file snort.conf has necessary permission and ownership. The directory /etc/snort should contain "chmod -R 5775" level permission. If you are installing it from source, you would be always able to copy the snort.conf to /etc/snort.

Comment: are you saying the snort.conf is supposed to exist before snort gets installed?